# Permutation on alphabets to form words.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Annie has ten cards, which are labelled:

B, D, F, F, F, G, M, M, X, Y.

By arranging these ten cards, a “word” is formed. Example: MYDFMXGFFB

(i) Determine the number of different “words” that could be formed with the ten
cards.

(ii) Determine the number of “words” which begin and end with
F, and in which the two letters M are consecutive?

Sorry I'm entirely new to permutation, would be super grateful if there are detail explanations.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: ai) i thought it going to be 10! but it wasn't.

Comment: aii)i thought since it begins and end with f and 2 consecutive m means 4 fixed so i thought its 6! but the ans is wrong.

Comment: i) It shouldn't be 10! as some letters are repeated,thus their arrangement doesn't makes any sense.

Comment: ii) the two f's are fixed but the M's aren't .They just behave as a single entity in the arrangements.

Comment: **Hint:** For the first question, choose three of the ten positions for the Fs, choose two of the remaining seven positions for the Ms, then arrange the distinct letters B, D, G, X, Y in the remaining five positions.

Comment: i understand now so for ai) should be 10!/3!*2! in order to exclude the duplicates?

Comment: thanks alot everyone! i got it i understand now!